# How to pass data from view to a callout component in flex (not the other way around)

Tags: apache-flex, view, callout

I have a callout and I want to get data from the View that will be passed to the callout. My callout is not inline, it is in a separate mxml file.

Like for example, I have a string in my View and when I click a button, my callout will open and the string from the View will be displayed inside the callout.

I hope someone can help. My problem is much bigger but I think with that simple example, I can get any idea on how to pass an object from a View to a Callout.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance to the Callout; just set a variable.

Inside your CallOut component, do something like this:

```
public var myValue : MyValueType;
```

After the callout is created, from within your view, you can do this:

```
myCallout.myValue = theValueIWantToSendIn;
```